# When to throw an exception and when to just return?

Tags: php, error-handling, design-principles

Sometimes functions fail to do what they say they do. When this happens, some functions throw an exception (e.g. PDO constructor) and others just return (e.g. `mysql_connect` would return `false`).

I have many times had to choose between one of these approaches over the other and I wonder if there is a design principle that deals with this.

Answer (score 2):

Returning `false` on error is considered to be an old practice, today, it's considered a bad one.

`mysql_connect` is a very old (2002) functions, before PHP implemented Exceptions or an OOP interface.

`PDO` is a newer, more recent (and more recommended) interface for accessing the database, and as such, it throws errors in the form of `PDOException`s.